# understanding how PreventDefault and DefaultPrevented work with custom events

Tags: jquery

I am just looking at this bootstrap Jquery code here, in [carasoul.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/carousel.js#L132), I am having a small difficulty understanding how defaultprevented and preventDefault work with custom Events. Have a look here at the bootstrap code:

```
var relatedTarget = $next[0]
var slideEvent = $.Event('slide.bs.carousel', {
  relatedTarget: relatedTarget,
  direction: direction
})
this.$element.trigger(slideEvent)
if (slideEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return
```

see this check here  `if (slideEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return` basically I don't understand how `isDefaultPrevented())` can be used with a custom event , I tried creating a demo here :

```
var slideEvent = $.Event('slide');

$('a').on('click' , function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $(this).trigger(slideEvent);
})

$('a').on('slide' , function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
})

if (slideEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        console.log('is default prevented');
}
```

but somehow the below block of code never console.log's :

```
if (slideEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        console.log('is default prevented');
}
```

maybe I am doing it the wrong way. Can somebody explain? All I want to do is understand how PreventDefault() and DefaultPrevented work with custom events and I want a working demo so that I can understand better.

Here is a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vdjhbpew/)** of what I have tried-

Comment: @A.Wolff YUp ! works fine now , but even in the bootstrap code , e.DefaultPrevented() is not in the same block as e.preventDefault() ? :D can you explain whats happening there ?   see here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/carousel.js#L132

Comment: I removed comment because it was not relevant regarding why this is used by this plugin. But i guess, this is to handle case where developper wants specifically prevent default behaviour, which is... i have no idea, sorry :(  I mean something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/vdjhbpew/2/

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks for trying , i'll Go through your fiddle !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking at it from a user's perspective. You should think of it from a developer's perspective. Consider the following example. In this example, we are giving the user the following functionality:

1. When the user clicks on a link our *plugin* will display an alert
2. There are two possibilities:

   1. The user might use our feature (of seeing the alert)
   2. Or might want to define their own functionality.

---

Lets define our plugin

```
$('a').on('click', function (e) { // As per our feature we will act on clicking a href
    var slideEvent = $.Event('slide'); // lets create our custom event
    e.preventDefault(); // of course we don't like hrefs
    $(this).trigger(slideEvent); // We should throw a slide event when the link is clicked
    if (slideEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) { // but if the user does not want to see our default event, they will preventDefault and we should stop our feature
        alert('is default prevented');
        return;
    }
    alert('clicked on href'); // our default feature is to display alert.
});
```

How is this feature consumed now ?

In this case the user chooses to use the default feature and so on click *clicked on href* is seen.

```
$('#case1').on('slide', function (e) {
   // e.preventDefault();

});
```

In this case, the user choose to define a custom functionality and hence `e.preventDefault` is used. (Which is caught in our plugin's definition in `isDefaultPrevented()`)

```
$('#case2').on('slide', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

---

Full example:

```
$('a').on('click', function (e) {
    var slideEvent = $.Event('slide');
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).trigger(slideEvent);
    if (slideEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        alert('is default prevented');
        return;
    }
    alert('clicked on href');
})

$('#case1').on('slide', function (e) {
   // e.preventDefault();

});
$('#case2').on('slide', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

```js
$('a').on('click', function (e) {
    var slideEvent = $.Event('slide');
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).trigger(slideEvent);
    if (slideEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        alert('is default prevented');
        return;
    }
    alert('clicked on href');
})

$('#case1').on('slide', function (e) {
   // e.preventDefault();
    
});
$('#case2').on('slide', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
a {
    font-size: 3em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" id="case1">Case 1</a>
 <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" id="case2">Case 2</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

preventDefault(); is a function that makes u disable the default event for element like

```
<a href="http://example.com"></a>
<script>$(function(){
  $('a').preventDefault();
});</script>
```

when you click that link when the page is loaded it will not redirect you to the page.
but isDefaultPrevented(); will check if the default event is disabled or not.